# 'Sia ... sia' e 'sia ... che'

Tags: grammar

Qual è la struttura sintattica più propria, 'sia ... sia' o 'sia ... che'?

Se sono entrambe appropriate, ci sono ragioni per scegliere l'una piuttosto che l'altra?

C'è un'infinità di casi possibili, ma al fine di esemplificare, considerate questo dialogo:

> Giulietta: 'A me piacciono le pere, ma non le mele.'
>
> Rosalinda: 'A me, invece, piacciono sia le pere [sia]/[che] le mele.'

Anche se non saprei spiegare il perché, ho l'impressione che Rosalinda dovrebbe usare 'che', quantomeno per contrastare meglio i suoi diversi gusti — le piacciono le pere che a Giulietta, al contrario, non piacciono — circa le pere.

Comment: Di solito preferisco il sia/che, trovo che evitare la ripetizione tenda a rendere la frase un po' meno pesante/pedante, ma ovviamente questo è solo un parere personale.

Comment: @MatteoItalia La ripetizione è invece la chiave per indicare la coordinazione; un po' come in *a uno a uno*, che molti, sbagliando, abbreviano calcisticamente in *uno a uno*. `;-)`

Comment: Da cui il detto popolare "Ti prendo a sberle a due a due finché non son' dispari".

Answer (score 12):

Sono corrette entrambe; diciamo che l'utilizzo del **"sia...sia"** è tradizionalmente più corretto in quanto l'uso del **"sia...che"** è entrato in auge dalla metà dell'Ottocento; prima, addirittura, il **"sia"** veniva coniugato ("siano...siano", "fosse...fosse") (Della Valle, Valeria, and Giuseppe Patota. Il salvaitaliano. Vol. 20. Sperling & Kupfer, 2000. pp.172-172). [Alcuni sostengono](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/node/591) che in particolari casi sia anche più univoca in quanto il **"sia"**  ha molto spesso un valore coordinativo-aggiuntivo mentre il **"che"** può essere utilizzato come pronome oltre che come congiunzione. Per esempio:

> I forum vengono utilizzati sia dagli italiani che hanno una lingua complicata e che non
>   hanno una buona istruzione che dai giapponesi che hanno una scrittura
>   molto difficile.

L'uso del **"sia"** potrebbe chiarire maggiormente il costrutto.

> I forum vengono utilizzati sia dagli italiani che hanno una lingua complicata e che non
>   hanno una buona istruzione sia dai giapponesi che hanno una scrittura
>   molto difficile.

In realtà anche in questi casi mi sembra che il senso si riesca a carpire in entrambe le versioni, soprattutto se ci aiutiamo con le virgole!

Comment: Tra quelli che conducono una crociata contro il _sia...che..._ citerei il correttore automatico di Microsoft Word. :-)

Comment: @Maruo Vanetti si sa che è un noto esponente dell'accademia della crusca!

Comment: @G M ...mi sono messo a non usarlo più solo per non essere perseguitato dalle sue lamentele.

Answer (score 1):

Sono entrambi corretti, come dice G M.
Io personalmente preferisco il "sia.. sia" perché lascia spazio ad aggiunte, mentre se uso il "sia... che" tipicamente dovrei terminare l'elenco ed ulteriori aggiunte stonerebbero.

Answer (score 0):

Non vedo differenze a parte la solita vecchia battaglia "prescrittivo" vs. "descrittivo". Oserei addirittura ipotizzare che con una ricerca mirata su Google si otterrebbero più "hits" di "sia ... che" rispetto all'altra forma.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Cos'è questo di "prescrittivo" vs. "descrittivo"?

Comment: Grazie! "Prescrittivo" è il concetto di una grammatica fossilizzata e governata dall' opposizione "corretto" vs. "scorretto" senza vie di mezzo. Di solito chi lo stabilisce sono istituzioni (anche se la "Crusca" è più flessibile dell'"Académie" in Francia, per esempio) compresi i dizionari. "Descrittivo" si riferisce all'osservazione di cosa dicono i parlanti (presupposto necessario per l'evoluzione di qualsiasi lingua). Detta in soldoni, un insegnante di solito è prescrittivo, mentre un linguista non lo è mai, limitandosi ad analizzare e spiegare fenomeni basati su dati concreti.

Comment: Grazie, @Nico: ho capito.

Comment: Di nulla :-). Tra l'altro queste due prospettive valgono chiaramente anche per il lessico.

Comment: La Crusca, da qualche secolo a questa parte, non ha proprio niente di prescrittivo e anzi, poveracci, devono giornalmente combattere contro le persone che lo credono, o per contestarla o per appellarsi alla Crusca affinché stabilisca chissà che norma. È un istituto di ricerca scientifica, come il CNR per la fisica e le altre scienze. Analogamente, i dizionari moderni registrano l'uso e non si sognano minimamente di dettare norme. Mi sa che sei rimasto indietro di almeno un secolo... :)

Comment: Può darsi visto che vivo all'estero da secoli... Tra l'altro non mi pare di aver scritto "i dizionari italiani" e "di solito" relativizza la proposizione seguente, come sicuramente saprai. Mi interesserebbe allora sentire la tua opinione riguardo a chi decida cosa sia "corretto" o "scorretto" in una lingua...

Comment: A proposito di dizionari, ti cito il Treccani riguardo al lemma "piuttosto": "Improprio l’uso di piuttosto seguito da che con il sign. di «o», «oppure», per indicare un’alternativa". Ora, mi pare che "improprio" sia un giudizio. Questo uso di piuttosto è recente, vero, ma un linguista lo descriverebbe cercando di spiegare il perché e senza valutarlo.

Comment: @DaG:  Credo che Nico abbia descritto quello che tradizionalmente accadeva con le lingue: 
per fortuna, con la lingua italiana non succede più, ma, purtroppo, gli "accademici" di altre lingue hanno ancora questa mentalità. Si veda, per esempio, [questo](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11367/2019/12/16).

Comment: @Charo. Grazie. Mi chiedo solo quali sarebbero i criteri scientifici riportati in " il fatto è che ultimamente la RAE fa uso di metodi assolutamente scientifici per decidere quali nuove parole includere nel suo dizionario".

Comment: @Nico:  Questo era ironico.

Comment: @Nico: È una questione lunga. Ovviamente parlavo solo della Crusca e dei dizionari italiani, dato il sito in cui siamo, e scusa se ci siamo fraintesi su questo. Quanto a «...chi decida cosa sia "corretto" o "scorretto" in una lingua», la risposta è semplice: nessuno, perché “corretto” e “scorretto” non sono categorie usate nella linguistica e lessicografia moderne. Sono l'uso, i fenomeni che fanno la “norma”. È un po' come in fisica. Non è che un fisico decide se sia corretto se l'elettrone ha una certa carica elettrica o no: misura qual è empiricamente.

Comment: Nessun problema per il fraintendmento :-) Ho scritto in termini generali perché i due concetti si applicano a qualsiasi lingua. Certo che è l'uso a formare la norma, ma quando ci sono opposizioni all'uso questo non verrà considerato "normale". Che la linguistica non usi queste categorie l'avevo scritto all'inizio. Riguardo ai dizionari non sarei così sicuro (vedi sopra "improprio"). Non so se sia riuscito a spiegarmi...

Comment: @DaG:  Un fisico fa un modello matematico che define, tra molte altre cose, cosa sia la carica elettrica dell'elettrone, dopodiché altri fisici fanno delle predizioni usando questo modello e poi altri fisici fanno esperimenti per vedere fino a che punto si avverano tali predizioni.

Comment: @Charo: Grazie, ma ho un'idea di come funzioni il metodo scientifico (e aggiungerei che anche il primo fisico della tua descrizione si è basato su precedenti osservazioni ed esperimenti, e così via ciclicamente). Mi riferivo solo al fatto che la linguistica moderna è prescrittiva quanto qualunque altra scienza, e cioè per niente.

Comment: @Nico: È interessante l'osservazione sull'“improprio”. Probabilmente in qualche introduzione o scritto di accompagnamento spiegano che cosa intendono di preciso, ma il fatto stesso che registrino quell'uso, ancorché accompagnandolo con un'avvertenza, conferma appunto che è all'uso che guarda il dizionario, non a una norma a priori. Io interpreto quell'“improprio” semplicemente come “attenzione, perché è un uso recente, che può creare malintesi e far arricciare il naso a qualche ascoltatore”, il che è utile per un lettore poco avveduto o uno straniero che impara l'italiano.

Comment: @DaG: Mi ero dimenticata di dirti che hai perfettamente ragione su quello che hai detto del primo fisico ;)

Answer (score 0):

Si pensi alla frase "mangerei una mela: sia essa matura, sia essa acerba.". Dato che si esprimono due ipotesi, non possono essere entrambe vere, e il congiuntivo aiuta a indicarlo.

Contraendo la frase, salta fuori "mangerei una mela: sia matura, sia acerba.". Oppure "amo le mele, siano esse rosse o siano verdi": se contratta ancor più, perdendo il plurale, diventa "amo le mele, sia rosse sia verdi".

Se però, invece di una più o meno legittima abbreviazione, si usa un meccanismo diverso (che non so definire) e si dice "amo le mele, sia rosse che verdi", si genera un anacoluto. Per me quella particella "che" è inspiegabile, o spiegabile forse dicendo che è una congiunzione buona per tutte le stagioni.

Credo che il ragionamento sopra possa essere una spiegazione del fatto che la locuzione "sia... sia..." è ritenuta più corretta, o per lo meno più tradizionale, rispetto a "sia... che...".