# Si usa "pubblicazione" come sinonimo di "post"?

Tags: word-usage, synonym

Recentemente ho scritto una [domanda su Spanish.SE Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3303) e l'ho fatto in castigliano (a differenza di quello che è accaduto su Italian.SE Meta o su French.SE Meta, che io sappia nessun "community manager" ha mai scritto su Spanish.SE Meta spiegando che la politica di SE è – o era – che tutti i post sui siti Meta debbano essere in inglese oppure bilingui inglese–altra lingua, quindi molti post si scrivono in spagnolo). Il titolo della domanda conteneva l'espressione "post cerrado" (cioè, "post chiuso"), ma un utente l'ha corretto subito come "publicación cerrada". Quando l'ho visto, mi sono accorta che in italiano esiste una parola molto simile, "pubblicazione", e mi sono chiesta se si dovesse anche usarla nell'ambito dell'informatica invece di "post", che infatti è un termine inglese.

Ora, la voce "post" appare nel [supplemento del 2009 al *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI24/GDLI_Supplemento_2009_Pagina_647.jpg) e immagino che questo significhi che il vocabolo "post" sia da parecchi anni molto diffuso in italiano (sono convinta che lo è anche in spagnolo solo che la RAE è un po' "lenta", per così dirlo, nell'includere certi neologismi nel dizionario e anche il fatto che sia "il dizionario" può diventare problematico). Allora, la mia domanda è: sapete se esiste qualche autore/autrice che usi "pubblicazione" come sinonimo di "post" nell'ambito digitale?

**Aggiornamento:**

Non mi referisco soltano all'espressione "post chiuso", ma anche ad altri contesti in cui si usa "post": per esempio, "ho scritto un post su Italian.SE o sul mio blog".

Comment: Il termine ***post*** viene comunemente usato nel linguaggio in rete con il significato : 

(Informatica) Messaggio testuale inviato a un social network come contributo personale. 
https://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/P/post.html Una ***pubblicazione digitale*** è la pubblicazione in rete di uno studio, una rivista etc. https://www.agfsolutions.it/pubblicazioni-digitali-cartacee-lo-dellarte

Comment: Grazie, @Gio: anche in castigliano "publicación digital" significa esattamente la stessa cosa.

Comment: Quindi post e pubblicazione  nel linguaggio digitale non sono la stessa cosa.

Comment: A dire il vero, personalmente l'uso di "publicación" come traduzione in spagnolo di "post" mi sembra strano, ma su Spanish.SE hanno deciso che questa è la traduzione standard (non so bene per quale criterio).

Comment: Non risponde alla tua domanda, ma segnalo che Wordpress, che è il CMS più diffuso al mondo, traduce "post" con "articolo" nella versione italiana.

Comment: Credo che gli spagnoli amino la loro lingua più di quanto gl'italiani amino la propria. Per un italiano, *troppo* sovente è un vanto usare termini inglesi che magari neppure capisce fino in fondo. Dire *post* è molto più figo che dire *nota*, *pubblicazione*, *articolo*, *commento*, *comunicazione*, *pensiero* eccetera. Per contro, a volte la parola inglese invece di un equivalente italiano è molto più precisa: se in italiano dico "mouse", non si può intendere altro che il mouse del computer.

Comment: @linuxfan: Invece ti posso assicurare che è tutto il contrario (questo l'ho letto molte volte scritto da italiani e penso sia un mito). Il problema è che la *Real Academia Española*, un'istituzione privata, come lo può essere l'Accademia della Crusca o la Treccani (ma che riceve tantissimi soldi pubblici), ha il monopolio della lingua e, purtroppo, ha ancora una concezione troppo prescrittiva e poco scientifica del linguaggio, come si commentava [qui](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/11474).

Comment: Per farti un esempio, dopo moltissimi anni in cui "whisky" veniva usato in testi in spagnolo (sebbene non era ammesso dalla RAE), un buon giorno la RAE disse: vabbè, potete usarlo, ma lo dovete scrivere "güisqui". Ecco il risultato:

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=whisky%2Cg%C3%BCisqui&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhisky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cg%C3%BCisqui%3B%2Cc0

Comment: E per fare un esempio più recente, guarda [qui](https://elpais.com/elpais/2018/03/28/icon/1522232572_682924.html) l'immagine con i termini "guasap", "wasap", "guasapear", ecc. Mi dispiace, ma io proprio  non me la sento di scrivere "guasap" o "wasap" invece di "WhatsApp". Non si è ancora arrivato al "Luigi Braccioforte", ma...

Comment: Capiamoci però: whisky, whatsapp e Louis Armstrong sono nomi propri e vanno bene come sono. Ma ci sono ottime parole italiane per trend, soft, summit, convention, news, e letteralmente decine di altre parole che sul momento non mi vengono: ogni volta che ascolto la televisione mi sale pressione arteriosa.

Comment: Completamente d'accordo, @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica!

Answer (score 1):

Il termine "pubblicazione" non l'ho mai sentito. Si incontra a volte il termine "filone chiuso": https://www.achyra.org/cruscate/app.php/help/faq?sid=647aa4003d87acd82647e263d8a00e9c#f3r7

Comment: Grazie, @Nico: a me sembra, però,  che "filone" sia un termine di uso specifico dei fori, quindi non lo vedo come sinonimo di "post".

Comment: Filone corrisponde a qualsiasi "thread" in cui ci si scambino opinioni.  Ora, a ben pensarci, quando si chiude un post, si blocca anche tutto lo scambio. "Pubblicazione" ha in italiano un senso piuttosto scientifico, ma forse ormai si usa anche in questo contesto.

Comment: @Charo "Fori" non è il plurale di forum, a proposito. Il plurale latino è fora, neutro della seconda declinazione.

Comment: Hai ragione, @FedericoPoloni, ma è il plurale di "foro", no? E nel link della risposta di Nico si usa il termine "fòro".

Comment: @Charo Uh, OK, giusto se uno vuole usare la versione italianizzata allora è il plurale corretto.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni, non che tu abbia detto il contrario, ma specifico per pignoleria: il plurale di *forum* in **italiano** è *forum*.

Comment: @is.cattabiani questo è il tipo di pignoleria che mi piace. Anche perchè in italiano "foro" comunemente ha altri significati.